# ¿Podríamos permitir preguntas que sean "listas de cosas"?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

Las "preguntas lista" son aquellas que piden "frameworks web en lenguaje X", "bibliotecas para hacer Y en lenguaje Z" y han sido tratado extensamente en Stack Exchange. Aquí hay un ejemplo de nuestro sitio en español:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10503/cual-es-la-mejor-librer%c3%ada-para-leer-archivos-excel-en-formato-xls-xlsx-xlsb-p

Estas preguntas suelen ser cerradas por estar basadas en opiniones, tal y como explica la FAQ.

Sin embargo, se ha visto que bien formuladas pueden ser tremendamente útiles. **¿Podríamos aceptarlas restringiéndolas un poco y siguiendo algunas reglas?**

- Siempre deben versar sobre la temática del sitio
- Las "preguntas lista" se deben hacer wiki de comunidad
- Cada respuesta debe tener **una y solo una** opción, para poder votarlas en consecuencia
- Las respuestas no se deben limitar a dar un enlace, sino que tienen que incluir también una pequeña explicación que dependerá de la pregunta
- La comunidad debe tratar de mantener las respuestas actualizadas para que puedan servir de consulta en el futuro.

¿Qué opinan?

Comment: Yo pienso que sigue siendo una pregunta muy amplia. Sería mejor si la pregunta fuese algo como "utilizo el framework foo que hace bar pero no consigo hacer quo. ¿Alguna idea de cómo conseguirlo?" La pregunta en este formato está delimitada y no se presta para opiniones netamente personales como gustos o predilecciones. Otro tema es preguntar "¿cómo puedo hacer foo con el lenguaje X?" Y se puede responder "el framework bar lo hace así: `quo`", lo cual también es conciso y directo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza respecto a la segunda pregunta de ejemplo que pones, "cómo abrir formatos excel en asp.net" es exactamente igual pero ha sido cerrada por estar basada en opiniones. Eso es precisamente lo que pretendo evitar.

Comment: Creo que no se entendió mi ejemplo en el último caso. La pregunta es cómo lograr hacer eso, no "recomiéndenme un framework para hacer foo con el lenguaje X". Además esas preguntas suponen que por lo menos debes haber investigado algo.

Comment: No creo que sirva en este formato, las librerías tienden a quedar en desuso y acabaremos con respuestas que tengan muchos votos frente a otras librerías mas nuevas y eficaces que tengan menos votos.

Comment: Puede funcionar si hay una sola respuesta wiki comunitaria con la lista y las aclaraciones del caso como [este](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before) ejemplo (que es una lista, pero no de librerías). Sin embargo, todavía no hay suficientes usuarios para hacer el mantenimiento adecuado de este tipo de respuestas.

Comment: De forma mayoritaria, las búsquedas que se hacen en SO se quedan en las primeras respuestas más votadas. Creo que es más interesante tener preguntas separadas con cada opción posible que agruparlas en una sóla lista. El mantenimiento es más simple y permite dar más visibilidad en el *timeline*  de las nuevas propuestas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por ahora, intentemos continuar formulando preguntas específicas que eviten la necesidad de involucrar las opiniones.  Como dice Luiggi Mendoza y ChemaCortes:

> La pregunta en este formato está delimitada y no se presta para opiniones netamente personales como gustos o predilecciones.

y

> Creo que es más interesante tener preguntas separadas con cada opción posible que agruparlas en una sóla lista. El mantenimiento es más simple y permite dar más visibilidad en el timeline de las nuevas propuestas

En un futuro, pienso que lo mejor será tener estas listas como Wikis, pero no tenemos los números suficientes para poder estar al tanto de los cambios necesarios para que las listas estén actualizadas. Estoy de acuerdo con lo que menciona RND:

> ...las librerías tienden a quedar en desuso y acabaremos con respuestas que tengan muchos votos frente a otras librerías mas nuevas y eficaces que tengan menos votos.

Enfoquemonos mejor en seguir creando preguntas útiles. Podemos volver a platicar sobre esto en unos meses.

¡Gracias por tu sugerencia!