# ¿Qué clase de reglas o patrones se utilizan para cerrar preguntas que están dentro del alcance del sitio?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, votos-de-cierre

Durante la revisión de reportes que realizo, veo muchas preguntas que se cierran y que están dentro del alcance del sitio. Preguntas como las que siguen (actualmente re abiertas):

- [Crear una cuenta regresiva para mi website en función de plays de SPOTIFY](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18045/227)
- [Problema con Buttons y TextBox con el Titulo del form](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18063/227)
- [Como crear una capa de virtualización de Servicios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/17894/227)
- [hacer SQL Injection desde control ComboBox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/17781/227)

Cabe considerar que para que una pregunta esté dentro del alcance del sitio, no solo debemos tener en cuenta que la pregunta sea asociada a programación, también se aceptan otros temas tal como se mencionan aquí: [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/227) (si no lo han revisado, es buen momento de hacerlo).

Quizás yo estoy siendo muy admisible al re abrir estas preguntas. Por lo cual mi duda es: ¿qué clase de reglas o patrones detectan en preguntas como estas para votarlas a cierre? Sobretodo aquellas preguntas que se cierran como "demasiado amplia". Me gustaría saber la opinión de los votantes a cierre a nivel de comunidad y ver si en realidad yo estoy equivocado al re abrir estas preguntas o si estamos siendo demasiado estrictos con las preguntas publicadas en el sitio.

Nota: no espero que alguien diga "no se cierran, se ponen en espera". Comprendo cómo funciona este sistema desde hace años y desde que se instauró el cambio en SO. Para más información al respecto, se puede revisar en el faq oficial [What is a “closed” or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/182862)

Comment: Marco +1 porque me parece una pregunta que se debe discutir, más allá de estar en total desacuerdo con lo expuesto.

Answer (score 4):

#### Resumen

Difiero en todo lo expuesto. Creo que hay un error de interpretación dentro de la pregunta: "demasiado amplia" y "fuera del alcance" no son lo mismo. Poner en pausa esas preguntas apuntaba a que se clarifique la pregunta, y así lograr una mejor calidad en el contenido de SOes.

---

#### ¿Demasiado Amplias?

Citando a la pregunta:

> se cierran y que están dentro del **alcance** del sitio.

Y después se citan 4 preguntas cerradas como "**demasiado amplias**".

Creo que tenemos una diferencia fundamental en la interpretación. Para mí, pueden estar las 4 dentro del alcance, pero eso no tiene nada que ver con los motivos de por qué se cerraron. **Si no estuvieran dentro del alcance, se hubieran cerrado como "No relacionado porque..."**.

---

> Sobretodo aquellas preguntas que se cierran como "demasiado amplia". Me gustaría saber la opinión de los votantes a cierre a nivel de comunidad

En la ventana de cierre, en "Demasiado amplias" dice:

- > <sub>Existen muchas respuestas posibles, o las buenas respuestas son
  > demasiado extensas para este formato.</sub>

Sin duda, "demasiado amplia" deja lugar a diferencias en lo que cada uno considera que aplica, y esto sucede en prácticamente todo SE. Por ejemplo, desde mi punto de vista, "muchas respuestas posibles" incluye casos que aclarando mejor la pregunta, se acotaría la respuesta. Es decir, **así como está planteada, tiene más respuestas posibles de lo que podría tener**. Pero sobre todo, pienso eso en casos donde estoy convencido de que un mínimo esfuerzo de la persona que está preguntando, llevaría a una mejor calidad de las preguntas en SOes -eso es lo que se busca! Me interesa formar el hábito de exigir preguntas que tengan un esfuerzo por resolver y exponer el tema claramente en todo lo que sea *razonable* antes de preguntar.

Irónicamente, la interpretación del motivo "demasiado amplia", puede ser... *demasiado amplio*! :-)

Así también, en cuanto a que "las buenas respuestas son demasiado extensas" creo que aplican casos en que si se agregara [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), mejoraría toda la publicación. Todos sabemos que hay casos que no lo requieren, o casos que la experiencia de quien está preguntando ni siquiera le permite llegar a elaborar un ejemplo, donde no pudo siquiera arrancar con el código. Pero también sabemos que hay casos en que no incorporaron el código porque son nuevos en SOes y no están acostumbrados al formato de preguntas o, peor aún, por vagancia y buscando que otro se lo solucione mágicamente. Y también, a veces es preferible intentar guiarlo con comentarios, para que edite la pregunta, sin necesidad de dejarla en pausa. Entra en juego el factor tiempo: cuánto pasa sin que agregue lo que se le pidió, o qué contestó al comentario, si pensamos que tiene posibilidad de arreglarlo y no merece ser puesta *bajo la alfombra*, o conviene sacarla de la cola de preguntas hasta que la edite y entre en cola de reapertura, priorizando el tiempo de la comunidad que quiere leer sólo preguntas que lo ameriten.

Acá es donde yo **confío en la experiencia de la comunidad para distinguir cuándo dejarlas en pausa para exigir mayor esfuerzo en la elaboración de la pregunta**.

Personalmente prefiero no estar tan ajustado literalmente a las reglas de cada motivo de cierre, priorizando por sobre todo como motivo válido de cierre:

- La forma en que interpretamos el contenido de la pregunta y la experiencia de la comunidad en cuanto a qué preguntas llegan a buen puerto.
- La experiencia para distinguir las preguntas que se resuelven con una muy sencilla búsqueda en Google, exigiendo que si se intentó resolver, se explique qué se encontró (o en qué busqueda no está encontrando soluciones) y por qué no le funcionó lo que encontró o puntualmente qué no está entendiendo dentro de lo que encontró.
- **El tiempo que la comunidad le dedica a leer preguntas es valioso**. Deberíamos buscar que sea sobre preguntas que hayan logrado exponer el problema de la mejor forma posible (hasta donde pueda hacerlo quien pregunta), y dejar en pausa al resto hasta que se editen en preguntas bien expuestas.

---

#### ¿Qué hacer?

> ver si en realidad yo estoy equivocado al re abrir estas preguntas

Creo que estás equivocado por no estar permitiendo ni incitando a que se mejore la calidad del contenido del sitio. Desde mi humilde opinión, hubiera contactado al usuario para buscar que agregue más detalle o, en su defecto, que explique por qué no pudo llegar a más de lo que expuso. En la ventana de cierre también dice:

- > <sub>Añade detalles para reducir el conjunto de respuestas o separar un problema ...</sub>

Según lo entiendo, **no quiere decir que la pregunta no debería estar en SOes, sino que debería estar mejor**.

---

> o si estamos siendo demasiado estrictos con las preguntas publicadas en el sitio.

Al contrario, y quiero ser totalmente explícito en esto: es buscando el objetivo de lograr un sitio de buena calidad por sobre todo. Me parece que eso cautiva a los usuarios que se busca, revisando colas de preguntas de calidad. Si quisiera un lugar donde se pregunte cualquier cosa sin esfuerzo y se obtenga un resultado, iría a Yahoo Respuestas. Para mí, buenas preguntas son la mejor garantía para que crezca SOes.

---

#### Estrategia durante esta etapa del beta de SOes

Reconozco que al estar en beta, en algún punto hay que ser más permisivos, para que haya más usuarios frecuentes. Es la eterna dicotomía entre lograr un sitio de expertos versus un alto número de usuarios conectados. Y hay que buscar un balance entre ambos, pero no a cualquier costo. Me parece que las preguntas que son demasiado amplias son uno de los motivos principales del por qué hay [poco porcentaje de respuestas a las preguntas](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish). ¿O no les pasa que al leer una pregunta que no muestra esfuerzo, no dan ganas de responder? Pero también sé que convendría buscar mejores formas a la hora de brindar ayuda, [no comentar simplemente "qué intentaste" o "agregá el código"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348/127), sino compartir conocimiento. Tomo lo que marcaste como una buena propuesta para mejorar este aspecto, de **intentar entre todos explicar de la mejor forma posible qué es lo que faltó poner en una pregunta antes de ponerla en pausa**.

Tu pregunta es excelente (más allá de que no haya acordado con tu visión), y creo que es algo que tenemos que tener presente y seguir enfatizándolo.

Comment: Si una pregunta es demasiado amplia, no está claro lo que se pregunta o cae sobre cualquier otro motivo de cierre, simplemente está fuera del alcance del sitio. Y para recalcar, las preguntas que he reabierto sí se pueden responder (algunas de ellas ya contaban con respuestas, a otras les brindaron una respuesta luego que la he reabierto, otras ponían en comentarios que podían recibir respuesta pero estaban cerradas). Esa es mi preocupación, que por buscar la "calidad" del sitio de manera ciega se cierran preguntas que sí pueden responderse.

Comment: En la pregunta: `esté dentro del alcance del sitio`...`, no solo`...`sea asociada a programación, también se aceptan otros temas`. <-- Ese fue tu argumento, sin mencionar nada más. No vi argumentos referidos a "demasiado amplia", por eso me pareció importante remarcar la diferencia... Por otro lado, entendí tu punto de vista y estoy de acuerdo en que hay que buscar un buen balance entre calidad y cantidad, pero como escribí, no creo que el hecho de que puedan recibir respuesta sea motivo suficiente. Ahí es donde diferimos totalmente... (sigue)

Comment: ...  No estoy juzgando si había que abrir o no esas 4, pero en las que había un comentario pidiendo más información al OP (y la comunidad estaba de acuerdo), y no hubo respuesta a ese comentario, creo que se debía buscar una respuesta antes de reabrir. **Mi preocupación**: que por querer atraer a más público baje la calidad y se pierdan usuarios con mayor experiencia... Tampoco quiero ser tan radical, es cuestión de buscar un buen balance.

Comment: En estos ejemplos por lo menos hay comentarios. En otros casos que ya he re abierto las preguntas son simplemente cerradas sin ningún comentario y al leerlas son perfectamente válidas, luce más a que votan a cierre por desconocimiento del tema más que por querer mantener la calidad del sitio. Si vuelvo a encontrar ese tipo de preguntas, colocaré los enlaces en la pregunta para que se puedan evaluar (actualmente no las tengo, es trabajo que se viene haciendo por días)

Comment: Si fuese así, estaríamos hablando de problemas distintos, y quizás una pregunta con un significado totalmente diferente a lo que planteaste. Sería una propuesta para que se acompañe mejor a nuevos usuarios (sin relacionarlo a los motivos del cierre... no sé, espero a tus ejemplos). De nuevo, sé que hay que ser algo prermisivo en el beta, pero también sé que en mi caso personal, estaría más tiempo en el sitio si no hubiese tanta pregunta que no muestra esfuerzo alguno.

Comment: @Luiggi - Debo darte la derecha en algo: desde que contesté esto (hace 1 semana) a hoy, estuve más atento y encontré muchísimos casos con votos de cierre con los que no estaba de acuerdo y seguramente encajan en lo que querías abarcar en tu pregunta. Si tu pregunta fuese exclusivamente sobre eso (con ejemplos menos controversiales, sin mencionar el post de temática de SOes en meta, ni tu decisión de reabrirlas), mi respuesta hubiese sido lo opuesto a lo que expuse.

Comment: por favor y todos, siéntanse libres de publicar una pregunta en meta para discutir preguntas que creen que han sido cerradas injustamente así como preguntas que deberían estar cerradas con puntaje positivo pero siguen abiertas.

Answer (score 3):

Para mi, las reglas están determinadas por esta publicación: [Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). La función de este tema como estándar para la definición de alcance es clara y evidente, los tópicos que propone como aceptados son bastante objetivos.

- un problema específico de programación, o
- un algoritmo de software, o
- herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es
- un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software

El mensaje es claro, acepta lo que está aquí, con las reservas que publica después (depuración, errores tipográficos y deberes escolares).

El grave problema de aceptar las temáticas de  [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/227) es precisamente la forma en la que lo menciona el OC, que dice (cito): *"también se aceptan otros temas tal como se mencionan aquí"*. En ese tema hay 6 propuestas con votos negativos, dos respuestas con más de 10 votos, 5 respuestas que tienen entre 10 y 6 votos y una con un solo voto. **¿Se van a aceptar *TODAS* las propuestas de ese tema, solo las que tengan mas de 10 votos, todas las que tengan votos positivos?**.

Las reglas para aceptar un tema no deberían aceptar interpretaciones de este tipo tan subjetivas o sin ningún orden (las reglas en general deberían ser objetivas, claras e inopinables).

### Mi propuesta

Ya que existe la posibilidad de opiniones subjetivas, sobre todo en la opción de *pregunta demasiada abierta*, mi opinión es **que se respete la voluntad de los usuarios que han votado por cerrarla**. Es la opinión de muchos contra la opinión de un solo moderador.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo y muy bien expuesto! Además, yo agregaría más detalle sobre lo que hacemos al "interpretar" una pregunta... Formalmente puede estar en tema ("es de programación"), pero la forma en que se expone, lo que se hizo para depurar (o lo que no se hizo), el esfuerzo mostrado por resolverlo (versus publicar y que te lo resuelva otro), etc... todo eso juega a la hora de "interpretar" si se debería cerrar, no solamente si está asociada a un tema.

Comment: La opinión de muchos no significa que sea la mejor o la más adecuada. Todavía ni salimos del beta y veo que la comunidad es tan exigente (o quizás más) que la comunidad del sitio en inglés. Y por si no lo notaste, son preguntas que sí pueden ser respondidas pero veo que suelen cerrarlas como si estuviesen mal planteadas. No es que yo re abra preguntas por ir en contra de la voluntad de los usuarios, sino que creo que cometen un abuso de esa voluntad. Por ello, vuelvo a preguntar: ¿por qué votar a cerrar preguntas que realmente sí están dentro del alcance del sitio?

Comment: Yo nunca dije que la opinión de la mayoría sea la mejor o la más adecuada. Claro que noté que las preguntas pueden ser respondidas (la primera pregunta sobre Spotify tiene una respuesta mía). Vuelvo a contestar que el alcance actual es muy claro, el alcance ampliado acepta demasiadas interpretaciones. Mi opinión no ha cambiado, **se deberían respetar los votos de cierre**. En cualquier caso, estoy seguro que en los casos que consideres conveniente, los moderadores del sitio tomarán una mejor decisión.

Comment: No nos olvidemos que poner en pausa una pregunta no es definitivo. Muchas preguntas buenas pueden pasar por ese ciclo. Creo que nos estamos olvidando de esa parte del proceso... ¿Por qué no dejar que la comunidad lo ponga en pausa, se edite y la comunidad la vuelva a abrir? Se eleva el contenido, se mantiene limpia la cola de preguntas del sitio y al fin y al cabo esa pregunta que era (o podía estar cerca de ser) demasiado amplia, puede pasar a ser una pregunta excelente.

Comment: @Mariano *No nos olvidemos que poner en pausa una pregunta no es definitivo* para los usuarios nuevos (que son a quienes principalmente se les cierra las preguntas) lo es, no vuelven al sitio. Además, aquellas preguntas cerradas con puntaje 0 negativo, al cabo de 1 semana son eliminadas automáticamente. Esto es lo que me preocupa, pues es lo más común, en búsqueda de la "calidad" se tiende a espantar a la gente. ¿De qué sirve tener un restaurante limpio y de alta calidad si nadie va a comer allí?

Comment: @toledano no se trata de **respetar** los votos de cierre o no. Se trata de que cierren por los motivos adecuados.

Comment: Entonces hay que establecer, sin lugar a dudas, cuáles son los motivos adecuados para cerrar una pregunta. Sin ambiguedades ni interpretaciones. Obvio, hay que enseñar y aprender, pero motivos claros de cierre permitirian a los usuarios que así lo deseen modificar su pregunta para cumplir con los estándares que a todos nos convienen. Un solo conjunto de reglas en un solo lugar. Un periodo de adaptación. La calidad cuesta, pero cuesta mas no tenerla. ¿Queremos un restaurante lleno de gente pero que sólo sirve basura gratis?

Comment: @Luiggi En cuanto a los usuarios nuevos, me imagino que también debe haber nuevos con preguntas aceptadas, contestadas y no vuelven, pero ¿hay estadísticas como para ponderar lo que estás diciendo? Porque diferimos, veo muchas sin responder, podrían responderse si estuviesen mejor y siempre veo la cola de reapertura vacía. Creo que en muchos casos un usuario nuevo que no escribe claramente, no es porque es nuevo, es porque prefirió escribir así. Igual que toledano, realmente creo que el restaurante vacío no se resuelve así. Una campaña publicitaria sobre SO puede resolver ese problema.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso particular, mandé un reporte como pregunta amplia en el tema **Como crear una capa de virtualización de Servicios**.

Mi opinión particular para realizar cualquier acción se basa en la interpretación de las reglas (que conozco) y de las preguntas, respuestas y comentarios que encuentro en Meta de usuarios con experiencia y reputación, y que están relacionadas precisamente con *que se permite y que no*.

Así en una búsqueda rápida (no recuerdo todos los temas leídos al respecto):

---

[Centro de Ayuda > Preguntas > ¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Al final del artículo:

**Algunas preguntas no son pertinentes incluso si encajan con una de las categorías mencionadas anteriormente:**
3. Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.

Entiendo que no se limita a un trabajo escolar, sino a cualquier tarea solicitada del tipo: *esto como se hace que ni he buscado en Google...*

O del tipo: *necesito hacer esto, pero debe tener esto, esto, esto...*

Y no mostrar ningún signo de haberse informado lo más mínimo sobre lo que está pidiendo.

Y lógicamente, para la respuesta sea necesario un cierto desarrollo, por poner un número, 30 minutos a 1 hora entre que verificas la información, planteas la respuesta, la ordenas para que sea coherente, poner formato, etc...

---

[¿Se puede hacer una pregunta de juicio de opinión por expertise?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/629/se-puede-hacer-una-pregunta-de-juicio-de-opini%C3%B3n-por-expertise)

---

[¿Podríamos permitir preguntas que sean “listas de cosas”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/585/podr%C3%ADamos-permitir-preguntas-que-sean-listas-de-cosas)

---

Además del último enlace que añades, **What is a “closed” or “on hold” question?**

La conclusión global es que preguntas con respuestas muy amplias, basadas en multitud de opciones o que generan debate no encajan. Se buscan preguntas con información suficiente y precisa que puedan obtener respuestas concretas que solucionen dudas o problemas entre otros, no solo al que pregunta, también pensando en futuros visitantes o usuarios con el mismo o similar problema.

La interpretación que pueda hacer, difiere de la de otros muchos con total seguridad, y ciertos matices, pueden hacer que realmente no sea tan amplia la respuesta como parece.

Pero en este caso no me parece que la pregunta esté formulada con la información suficiente para que alguien pueda aportar una respuesta concreta que resuelva la duda a el o a otro usuario con la misma inquietud.

Son los motivos expuestos entre otros los que valoro antes de enviar un reporte.

Comment: El caso particular que revisaste para poner en pausa no era una tarea escolar, ni buscaba que le resuelvan el código (lo dijo en el comentario). ¿No crees que deberían haber agregado un comentario pidiendo más información o solicitando lo que faltaba en la pregunta antes de ponerla en pausa? Más que nada porque vi que respondió al único comentario que le hicieron a los 3 minutos.

Comment: @Mariano No existe diferencia entre una tarea escolar u otra petición si se realiza de la misma forma. La puesta en común es buena, se aprende y se sacan conclusiones. He aportado mi punto de vista, con el que estarán de acuerdo o no. He argumentado el por que de mi decisión, por que de casualidad en una de las comentadas intervine. Y desde mi corta experiencia en _SOes_, de entre otras muchas, he puesto en conocimiento mi conclusión al respecto. Aprendo y estoy de acuerdo con mucho de lo comentado aquí. Pero a día de hoy, sigo manteniendo la misma postura.

Comment: No estoy diciendo ni que estaba bien ni que estaba mal ponerla en pausa, no opino sobre tu decisión, como verás [publiqué una respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/713/127) justificando algunos motivos para poner en pausa. Me refiero al mecanismo empleado, preguntándote si no crees que sería mejor agregar comentarios en la pregunta para llevar a que la mejoren antes de ponerla en pausa.

Comment: Si, y apoyo esa iniciativa, es más suelo preguntar e indagar para buscar la solución (a las mis pocas intervenciones realizadas me remito), pero cuando detectas que hay cierta actitud de trabajo/colaboración detrás de las preguntas. Pienso que debe ser mutuo el compromiso, y no tiene porque recaer todo el trabajo en el que responde. Lo contrario a esto, denota una gran falta de consideración hacia todos los que dedican su tiempo de forma altruista a compartir sus conocimientos y experiencias. ¿Que regla se crea para controlar un escenario de estas características? Se da con cierta frecuencia.

Comment: Vale la aclaración, ahora entiendo mejor tu postura y tu respuesta. Gracias