# Pregunta cerrada - ¿Por qué?

Tags: discusión

[Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/19589/7242) fue cerrada hace ya unos días.

El motivo de su cierre es "no está claro lo que se pregunta" pero no soy capaz de entenderlo.

Podría entender que se cerrara por ser "Demasiado ámplia" ya que quizá falta información para ayudar al usuario.

Podría entender también que se cerrara por "No está en el alcance definido en el sitio" ya que no hay código alguno en la pregunta pero sinceramente [no tengo claro](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/710/7242) lo que está o no dentro del alcance del sitio (y últimamente soy mucho más permisivo)

¿Podríais ayudarme a entender el motivo del cierre? Quiero aprender a saber exactamente el por qué de estos casos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo fui uno de los que voto por cerrarla en su momento. Creo que en mi caso  no voté por "no está claro lo que se pregunta" (aunque puede que recuerde mal), sino que que vote por "demasiado amplia" o "no está en el alcance definido dentro del centro de ayuda".

Algunos de los motivos:

- Se está pidiendo ayuda para un problema complejo incluyendo muy poco sobre el mismo, básicamente su descripción ("el rendimiento no es igual entre A y B").
- No sólo no se incluyó nada de código, pero es que tampoco se pusieron otros datos que sí podrían afectar: configuración del build, plugins, profiler, etc.
- El rendimiuento no es igual entre A y B. Aquí está A, pero B no está disponible para comparar.
- Es muy difícil saber qué puede afectar al rendimiento de una app sólo viendo dos imágenes (al menos son de parte de la configuración).
- La otra referencia al problema era un enlace a la página de descarga de la app (algo que me olió un poco a *spam*)

Comprendo que los puntos 2 y 3 son difíciles (o imposibles) dadas las restricciones de tamaño de texto y tipo de ficheros que se pueden subir al sitio. Pero eso también debería ser significativo: si el sitio no permite añadir información necesaria para encontrar la raíz del problema, quizás sea porque el problema no se ajusta al alcance del sitio.

Dicho esto... si realmente crees que la pregunta debería ser reabierta, seré el primero (o el segundo después de ti) en votar por ello.

Comment: Gracias por la contestación. Estoy 100% de acuerdo con lo comentas, y veo claro que la pregunta debería estar cerrada, sólo me preguntaba el *por qué*. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Para mí es irrecuperable la pregunta.

- No muestra ningún esfuerzo para depurarla.
- No da información que permita evaluar el caso efectivamente.
- Dista mucho de ser [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- Pero sobre todo, así como está planteada, **no tiene ninguna respuesta posible**.

---

Como motivo de cierre, creo que aplica mejor "demasiado amplia", pero también encuentro motivos dentro de "no está claro", definido en [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Y para mí, es más importante que se pongan en pausa este tipo de preguntas a que se defina bien cuál de los motivos aplica. Obviamente el objetivo es promover las preguntas de calidad, y que el autor pueda editarla a tal fin.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que era necesario ponerla en pausa, pero el autor, al ver el motivo, se frustró y ya no volvió al sitio para editar la pregunta.. Por eso comentaba que quizá no era el mejor motivo de cierre. En cualquier caso gracias por compartir tu opinión, que encuentro 100% correcta.

Comment: @MiquelColl Seguramente se puede acompañar muchísimo mejor al usuario, independientemente del motivo de cierre, pero intencionalmente quise responder exclusivamente a tu pregunta -el por qué. Y creo que no es tarde aún (el usuario [entró hace 14 hs](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/3828/tonimarquez84)). Sin embargo, yo priorizo por sobre todo el tiempo que la comunidad dedica en leer y responder preguntas. Cuanto menos tiempo se pierda en leer preguntas que no pueden tener respuesta, mejor.

Comment: Yo creo que también afecta que la pregunta es sobre un tema del cuál *no tengo ni idea*. Puedo ver que falta información pero *desconozco* si alguien experto en unity3d podría responderla (tiene pinta que NO). !Gracias por la aclaración @Mariano!

Comment: No concuerdo en que sea cerrada como demasiado amplia . Yo creo que para que una pregunta sea demasiado amplia significa que por lo menos tiene una o más posibles respuestas o una respuesta que sería muy extensa. Si la pregunta tal como luce, con la información que provee no se puede responder, entonces no está claro lo que se está preguntando.

Comment: @Luiggi respeto tu visión y es totalmente válida. Pero, más allá de que al menos 3 entendemos que puede ser *demasiado amplia*, y que creo que entra en un *gris* entre "*sin respuesta*" o que "*tiene demasiadas respuestas posibles*", el punto principal que intento expresar es: no me importa tanto el motivo, para mí es mucho más preponderante poner en pausa y potenciar el tiempo que la comunidad usa en leer preguntas. Hasta ahora no vi ningún argumento a favor de reabrirla, y sigo atento a si alguien puede demostrar lo contrario.

Comment: En mi respuesta explico cómo re abrirla pero lo único que recibo son votos negativos, lo cual refuerza mi teoría de que la comunidad solo piensa en "esta pregunta es mala, cerrémosla y mantengamos el sitio limpio" cuando el sitio debería estar limpio de usuarios con esas malas intenciones.

Comment: @Luiggi Por [lo expresado por Miquel Coll](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/743/127), la [respuesta de Alvaro Montoro](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/744/127), y mi visión, estoy convencido de que estaríamos totalmente de acuerdo en que si se edita para convertirla en una buena pregunta, votaríamos por reabrirla. En cuanto a tu respuesta, aclaro mi punto ahí.

Answer (score -4):

Lastimosamente mucha gente solo vota porque quiere "mantener el sitio limpio", pareciendo más autómatas que votan a cerrar sin explicar nada antes que pensar que somos personas y podemos entender motivos por los cuales se puede cerrar la pregunta, más allá de la explicación limitada que se brinda en el detalle del por qué la pregunta fue cerrada, en este caso el *Aclara tu problema específico o añade detalles adicionales para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas*.

En mi opinión, no está claro lo que se pregunta. Esto se debe a que no se tienen todos los elementos necesarios para analizar el problema dentro de la pregunta. Que haya un enlace donde se pueda acceder a la aplicación para analizarla no es bueno por dos cosas:

1. Sabemos que los enlaces a sitios externos se pueden romper, por ende las publicaciones deben ser auto contenidas.
2. La funcionalidad principal de enlaces a sitios externos es para brindar más detalle sobre lo que se está hablando.

Para re abrir la pregunta, yo diría que necesita ser editada con los siguientes puntos:

- Brindar más detalles técnicos de la aplicación: qué frameworks/tecnologías se utilizaron en su creación/construcción, en qué sistema operativo se realizaron las pruebas, con qué emulador y qué características tenía el emulador: cpu, gpu, ram, etc. Es probable que alguna combinación de estos elementos necesite unas optimizaciones o soporten alguna configuración que mejore su rendimiento.
- Explicar un poco la arquitectura de la aplicación. Este puede ser un tema amplio, pero por lo menos indicar un flujo básico de cómo se realiza el renderizado de las imágenes, o quizás hayan demasiadas operaciones intermedias entre los métodos de renderizado, ocasionando problemas.
- Resultados de un profiler que analiza la aplicación en tiempo de ejecución en un dispositivo real. Esto también puede ayudar a detectar dónde se encuentran los cuellos de botella en la aplicación.

Cabe resaltar que el código no es relevante para todas las preguntas, pero de ser posible mostrar código reproducible donde se pueda detectar el problema, ayudaría mucho más a no tener nada. Esto significa: tener la capacidad de crear un nuevo proyecto con el código aislado y ver que realmente ese es el fragmento que presenta problemas.

Comment: Gracias por contestar Luiggi, estoy de acuerdo con lo que comentas, yo también he visto que estábamos siendo *demiasiado* duros cerrando preguntas y he intentado ser mucho más comprensible, aún más con usuarios nuevos. ¿Es bueno que compartamos dudas de preguntas cerradas-no cerradas? No quiero llenar meta de *¿Por qué cerrada?*.. Estoy de acuerdo que la pregunta necesita actualizarse pero el motivo por el que se cerró ha echo que el usuario decida no invertir tiempo en editarla.. Un saludo.

Comment: @MiquelColl si el usuario no piensa actualizarla, no queda más remedio que dejarla cerrada.

Comment: @Luiggi Pensé que no hacía falta aclarar (y quise evitar personalizarlo), pero me equivoqué. Explico: **1** Estoy de acuerdo en que podría interpretarse como que *no está claro*, aunque para mí aplica mejor *demasiado amplia*. **2** Acuerdo en que una buena edición (que puede ser sin código) haría que se reabra, es más podría convertirse en una pregunta excelente... (cont.)

Comment: **3** Estoy más que en desacuerdo con el primer párrafo, voté -1 apenas lo leí, y no me gusta ver a alguien generalizando que los revisores (**especialmente los que pusieron en pausa esa pregunta**) parecen autómatas o tienen esa actitud.. Quizás si el motivo de cierre es limitado, es hora de ampliar los motivos de cierre. Los copiamos de SO, quizás ese fue el error. Creo que si es un problema que ya (al menos nosotros) identificamos en repetidas oportunidades, es hora de plantear el tema en meta: cómo mejorar motivos de cierre, qué articulos linkear... Si abrís el tema tendrás todo mi apoyo.

Comment: @Mariano La verdad los veo como autómatas porque las notificaciones que se reciben es "cerrado sin comentario" y porque no es la primera ni será la última vez que hacen eso. Un robot solo ejecuta una orden basado en su programación tal como es veo pregunta mala, voto a cerrar y sigo con mi vida. Ninguno de ellos suele comentar al respecto y eso refleja dos cosas: o son autómatas que solo votan a cierre o simplemente no les importa los usuarios cuya pregunta fue cerrada, prefieren el sitio antes que pensar en la otra persona. Y mantengo en pie lo que digo:

Comment: @Mariano nadie hasta ahora expone cómo es que se pudiese re abrir la pregunta, solo mantienen el hecho de que "puede ser re abierta", lo cual se deja a libre interpretación. Es más, puede ser editada pero sigue sin poder responderse, se cerrará nuevamente. Nadie brinda ideas para que realmente luzca mejor, y nadie brindó ni brindará comentarios antes de cerrar la pregunta, lo cual me parece pésimo de los votantes a cierre (con excepción de las preguntas que son spam neto).

Comment: @Luiggi La pregunta era "*¿Podríais ayudarme a entender el motivo del cierre?*". Yo di por sentado que [Miquel](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/743/127) entendía cómo podría reabrirse... Y, si bien sigo opinando todo lo contrario a que son autómatas o que no les importa, sí estoy de acuerdo que habría que comentar algo que ayude al autor de la pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano los autómatas seguirán cerrando sin comentsr, tenlo por seguro.

Comment: @Luiggi Mi visión: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close, pero lo que marcás fue discutido muchas veces (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216683/what-happens-to-new-users). Si identificas un caso, ¿no es tarea de un mod y audits?

Comment: @Mariano exacto. Y ese modelo se copia desde el sitio en inglés StackOverflow. Lo digo porque también he sufrido de ese comportamiento en mis primeros días en esta comunidad, pero recuerdo cuando participaba en otras comunidades de SE donde el comportamiento es **completamente distinto, más cordial y más humano**, quizás por el hecho de no ser desarrolladores (?) quizás porque los usuarios son mas pacientes y dejan comentarios tan siquiera antes de votar a cerrar para que los usuarios recapacitemos y actuemos acorde a ello (sí, esto me pasó en el sitio http://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Buff, no había visto todos estos comentarios. Des de mi punto de vista la comunidad de SO en español es **muy dura** aunque tengoq ue reconocer que en un inicio yo también cerraba *a saco*. A medida que ha pasado el tiempo (y sobretodo des de la publicación de Luiggi al respecto) intento dejar comentarios siempre que puedo, dejar abiertas preguntas que en el SO original se cerrarían y varias cosas para **ayudar** a los nuevos usuarios. Creo que **no** somos tan duros como la comunidad en ingles, pero es que la comunidad en inglés es **demasiado**!. Tenemos que ayudar más a los nuevos usuarios.