# Un gran poder conlleva una gran responsabilidad

Tags: discusión

Ya somos varios usuarios en la comunidad con poderes de revisión de cierre.

Eso es un poder importante, y como tal conlleva una gran responsabilidad.

Últimamente da la sensación que hay un grupo de usuarios con este poder que lo está utilizando con poca responsabilidad y eso es preocupante y nos está afectando.

Por ejemplo, la pregunta [¿Cual es la verdadera intención con las puntuaciones negativas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/788/7242) tiene varios comentarios como este:

Por [Luiggi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/788/cual-es-la-verdadera-intenci%C3%B3n-con-las-puntuaciones-negativas#comment1753_788):

> Tu idea es algo que trato de promover pero la muchedumbre que supuestamente tiene la razón y que quiere ver el sitio "limpio" (y lo sigo reiterando: son un grupo de autómatas que solo votan a cierre sin comentar como si fuesen máquinas). No necesitamos estos usuarios con malas intenciones, sin importar cuánto conocimiento y apoyo hayan brindado a la comunidad, este lado negativo hace más daño y es más fuerte. Y lo digo porque usualmente son los mismos usuarios que suelen votar a cierre/votar en negativo sin dejar comentario al respecto

Tenemos otras preguntas como [Pregunta cerrada - ¿Por qué?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/743/7242).

¿A qué viene todo esto?

Nos estamos encontrando con múltiples preguntas que son cerradas, **indistintamente de si son cerradas correctamente**, sin **ningún comentario**.

Es **muy importante** ayudar a los nuevos usuarios de la comunidad proporcionando ayuda para generar buenas preguntas y eso no se consigue cerrando indiscriminadamente.

**Si sois un usuario con poderes de cierre**. **Nunca** cerréis una pregunta sin dejar un comentario para ayudar al usuario a resolver el problema que os haga decidir cerrar la pregunta.

Vamos a poner un ejemplo. En la pregunta [Error, Estas filas exceden los límites al eliminar una fila en googlespreadsheet con javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20802/7242) en su presentación inicial no estaba claro lo que se preguntaba, pero tras dejar comentarios y hablar con el autor se pudo llegar a una [buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20813/7242).

**Si sois un usuario nuevo y os han cerrado una pregunta sin comentarios**. No dudéis en formular una pregunta aquí en meta pidiendo aclaraciones. Os vamos a ayudar.

Todo esto que os he contado es importante, pero ahora viene mi pregunta:

Si el grupo de usuarios con esta responsabilidad que está utilizando mal está delimitado. ¿Por qué no quitarles ese poder *temporalmente*? ¿Por qué no introducir los **[review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121)** como en el SO original?

Tendríamos que buscar una solución ya que esta situación frustra a muchos usuarios (yo *incluido*).

Comment: Tenéis toda la razón con esta discusión.

Comment: Estoy deacuerdo con lo que dice @Luiggi Mendoza y lo apoyo

Comment: Yo recientemente obtuve los privilegios de voto de cierre y espero estar usándolos bien, ya tuve algún rapapolvo en SOen al respecto e intento no actuar en preguntas que no me parecen claras y/o pertenecen a campos de los que no tengo conocimientos... si he cometido algún error me gustaría debatirlo. Por otro lado: tampoco me parece necesario añadir un comentario cada vez que se vota tomar alguna acción sobre preguntas/respuestas, eso ensuciaría los comentarios con datos que no aportan nada.

Comment: En The Workplace hay algo llamado _The Watercooler_ básicamente es para que algunos usuarios sean temporalmente suspendidos, es algo que ya está en Stack Exchange y se podría implementar...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ¿Por qué no quitarles ese poder *temporalmente*?

Es la tarea de un moderador, no de la comunidad. Si detectás un caso, reportalo.

> ¿Por qué no introducir los [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121) como en el SO original?

Comenté [lo mismo hace unos días](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/1691). Sin embargo, no tengo idea cuál es el costo de desarrollarlo. Y, si el costo es alto, puede haber otras prioridades. Debería haber una respuesta oficial a esto.

> Es muy importante ayudar a los nuevos usuarios de la comunidad proporcionando ayuda para generar buenas preguntas y eso no se consigue cerrando indiscriminadamente.

Antes de contestar, estuve revisando datos de cierre de preguntas, nada concluyente ([no soy el primero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216683/304899)). Podría presentar casos para argumentar a favor y en contra de si son significativos.

Personalmente creo que sería muchísimo más ventajoso volver a evaluar la lista de motivos de cierre, las descripciones que se muestran y la información presentada en la ayuda, para que quede más claro el motivo y qué debería hacer el usuario para convertirlo en una buena pregunta.

Entramos en un tema recurrente: cantidad versus calidad.

Desde mi punto de vista, este es el orden en el que pondero los cierres y comentarios:

1. Valorar el tiempo que la comunidad ya establecida le dedica al sitio
   (disminuyendo el tiempo que dedica en leer preguntas que no pueden ser respondidas).
2. Captar nuevos usuarios (discutido abajo).
3. SENTIDO COMÚN. Hay veces que hace falta comentar y veces que no.
4. Dar continuamente el ejemplo de lo que está bien preguntar [y lo que no](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92638/304899).
5. Obviamente, si ya hay un comentario, se vota ese comentario sin dejar otro.
6. Hay casos en los que se sobreentiende el motivo del cierre, y no haría falta un comentario, pero a veces [tardamos 15 horas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21881/127) en cerrar una pregunta. Un comentario corto puede ayudar a guiar, y no dejarlo esperando sin respuesta.
7. A veces el revisor está con poco tiempo. Personalmente prefiero que emita un voto calificado sin comentario antes de que no lo haga (viéndolo como excepción y no como regla).

> Si sois un usuario con poderes de cierre. Nunca cerréis una pregunta sin dejar un comentario para ayudar al usuario a resolver el problema que os haga decidir cerrar la pregunta.

Estoy de acuerdo con la cuestión de fondo que estás proponiendo, pero por motivos diferentes. No con el hecho de comentar *siempre*, pero sí con intentar acompañar a todo usuario nuevo para captarlo.

SOes está creciendo (lento, pero crece)

[image: Tráfico de quantcast para SOes]

y con usuarios de diferentes lados

[image: Distribución geográfica de quantcast para SOes]

Pero todavía nos falta bastante si nos comparamos con sitios "hermanos"

[image: Total usuarios en quantcast para *.stackoverflow.com]

#### Crecer en volumen debería ser el primer objetivo en común de todos nosotros.

Y, si todos tenemos esto presente a la hora de realizar una revisión, yo confío en el criterio de cada uno de los profesionales que forman parte de la comunidad para "remar hacia el mismo lado".

Lectura recomendada: [*A recipe to promote your site*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/).

**Y propongo:**

Si ven una publicación más o menos aceptable de un usuario con menos de 200rep, **voten +1** (estamos siendo muy tímidos con los votos, *[vote early, vote often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)*). ¡Esos 5 o 10 puntos son importantes para que siga aportando!

Comment: Bastante objetiva la respuesta @Mariano, la idea es ir formando la comunidad entre todos, y también "conocernos" como funcionamos.

Answer (score 6):

Personalmente [no comparto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/788/cual-es-la-verdadera-intenci%c3%b3n-con-las-puntuaciones-negativas#comment1756_788) la forma en la que se [expresa el moderador](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/788/cual-es-la-verdadera-intenci%c3%b3n-con-las-puntuaciones-negativas#comment1753_788) con respecto al tema, pero concuerdo con el fondo, algo debe de cambiar. Mientras tanto, así funciona el sitio y trataré de demostrarlo, citando las palabras del OC:

> Nos estamos encontrando con múltiples preguntas que son cerradas, **indistintamente de si son cerradas correctamente**, sin **ningún comentario**.

Hasta donde alcanzo a comprender el único requisito para cerrar una pregunta es que tenga el número suficiente de votos, **los comentarios no son un requisito**. Claro que se agradece la información que ayuda a clarificar una pregunta o una respuesta, pero es más un *debería* que un *debe*.

Me preocupa más la afirmación *"indistintamente de si son cerradas correctamente"*. ¿Quién tiene el poder de decidir si una pregunta se cerró correctamente? ¿Quién decide si un usuario tiene la razón o está equivocado? Si existe una persona o un grupo de personas que califica nuestras decisiones, *¿de qué sirve votar si otro decide y puede cambiar la decisión votada?*

La propuesta de quitarles los derechos ganados a ese grupo (a cualquiera) **equivale a expulsarlos del sitio** porque no opinan como la mayoría o el como cree el que manda, *censura* le llaman en el mundo real.

#### Notas

1. ¿Conocemos la cantidad de preguntas cerradas de esta manera?
2. ¿Qué porcentaje representan con respecto al total de preguntas?
3. Llevamos dos preguntas relacionadas con el tema, ¿cuál es el mecanismo para crear nuevas reglas o modificar las actuales?
4. ¿Cómo se realiza una auditoría de revisiones?

### Mi conclusión

1. La [teoría de la moderación](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) funciona como se espera.
2. Los casos especiales no son tan especiales como para romper las reglas (me refiero al supuesto *grupo de autómatas* y si, es del Zen de Python).
3. La parte lúdica del sitio, me refiero a los puntos y las medallas, forma parte importante de la experiencia general que ofrece la comunidad de StackOverflow y *no debería* ser limitada.
4. Las reglas actuales deben ser suficientes.
5. **No *debería* haber ningún cambio**.

Comment: Y sobre los review audits?

Answer (score 5):

**Sobre mi actitud con los cierres.**

En los casos en los que he tenido la oportunidad para votar por el cierre adopto una posición distinta. Son más las veces en las que voto por el no-cierre de una pregunta que aquellas en las que voto por el sí-cierre. Para las primeras, a las cuales considero no deben cerrarse, yo solía dejar un comentario en el que preguntaba por los motivos que los otros le habían dado para el cierre (casi siempre relacionados con el motivo "No relacionado: no parecer versar sobre programación"). Pero escasas veces, por no decir casi nunca, recibía una respuesta. Así que opté por la cómoda posición de no comentar motivos de cierre en las que votaba para no-cierre y simplemente limitarme a salvarlas de los cierres despiadados. Para aquellas en las que voto por sí-cierre pocas veces dejo un comentario, ya que considero que la gran mayoría de causas son lo suficientemente descriptivas (basadas en opiniones personales, no relacionadas, preguntas en inglés, no tienen nada que ver con programación, etc).

**Sobre la actitud del moderador con los cierres.**

Rechazo absolutamente la actitud del moderador, tratando a los usuarios del sitio como 'muchedumbre' y 'autómatas'. Le exijo a usted respeto por todos los miembros del sitio, los cuales trabajamos por el crecimiento de esta comunidad y realizamos las acciones por las cuales nos hemos ganado los méritos, que no los define usted, sino toda la comunidad. Le solicito respetuosamente ser más cuidadoso con sus comentarios y hacer un uso responsable de su posición.

**Sobre lo que ocurre actualmente**

Ignoro si es posible saber cuántas de todas las preguntas que se hacen a diario terminan cerradas por X o Y motivo (actualmente hay 377 preguntas cerradas de 6843: un 5,5% ¿es considerado alarmante?) lo que sí es cierto es que a diario encuentro una gran cola de preguntas para cerrar y la mayoría de los motivos aplica a 'No relacionado por no versar sobre programación'. Yo dudo mucho que deliberadamente exista un grupo de usuarios destinados a cerrar cuanta pregunta aparezca de forma malintencionada.

Los invito a comparar esta situación con el sitio en inglés, guardadas las proporciones la cantidad de preguntas que se cierran es abrumadora. Es evidente que este tipo de motivos de cierre en el sitio en español deberían encontrarse, ya que últimamente se ha convertido en un sumidero de preguntas no de programación sino de tecnología en general

**Sobre lo que debería ocurrir**

Dado eso último ¿de quién es la culpa? ¿de los usuarios que preguntan o de quienes cierran las preguntas? Yo considero que ambas partes juegan un papel importante: se debe pensar en cómo atacar esta situación de cara a educar a los usuarios que preguntan. Si sabemos que buena parte de las preguntas se cierran por no estar relacionadas con programación ¿de qué forma se le enseña a un usuario nuevo a limitarse a esto?. Si otro tanto de las preguntas son cerradas por ser demasiado amplias ¿cómo le estamos enseñando a los nuevos usuarios a definir de forma correcta el alcance de su pregunta? Si otro más es cerrada por estar basada en opiniones ¿cómo estamos instruyendo a los usuarios a evitar este tipo de preguntas o a transformarlas en algo con valor que tengan una repsuesta objetiva?

**Sobre lo que NO debería ocurrir.**

- No estoy de acuerdo con la censura ni con limitar este tipo de
  acciones. Eduquemos en vez de censurar.
- No estoy de acuerdo con dejar comentarios en todas las preguntas que se votan para cierre. Recalco que algunas causas de cierre son los suficientemente explícitas. Para aquellos sumideros como 'demasiado amplia' o 'basada en opiniones acepto dejar comentarios siempre y cuando eso oriente a aclarar o limitar el alcance. No veo posible (si alguien tiene un contraejemplo, lo agradecería) salvar o rescatar una pregunta que se cierre como 'No relacionada por no versar sobre programación'
- No estoy de acuerdo con dejar abiertas preguntas terriblemente mal formuladas, pero tampoco con cerrarlas sólo porque están mal formuladas. En ese sentido hay que educar a los usuarios a redactar mejor las preguntas, así como evitar que estas se cierren indiscriminadamente. Las preguntas de muy baja calidad considero yo, son naturalmente aptas para salvarlas.

**Sobre los review audits.**

Me parece que son bienvenidos. Pero si, de acuerdo al argumento del moderador, es la misma 'muchedumbre autómata' la que vota por cierres siempre entonces no serían de gran ayuda, pero como sé que no es así considero que sería bueno implementarlos aquí.

Comment: *actualmente hay 377 preguntas cerradas de 6843: un 5,5% ¿es considerado alarmante?* en realidad hay más preguntas pero que si no tienen respuestas y tienen puntaje de 0 o menor son eliminadas por el sistema luego de 1 semana de inactividad. Lo bueno (fuera de lo que opine la gente sobre las cosas que digo) es que ese síntoma de cerrar porque sí y no apoyar a los usuarios ha desaparecido momentáneamente. Pero lo que haré es tener un registro de todos esos usuarios que votan indiscriminadamente a cierre sin comentar ni apoyar a los usuarios.

Comment: Ni siquiera da luces de una disculpa pública frente a sus comentarios despectivos con los miembros de la comunidad, increíble.

Comment: No voy a tocar ese tema en meta, solo en la [sala de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) puesto que se trata de una idea larga y extendida y que sé que si publico una pregunta o respuesta serán más los votos en contra que los favorables. Fuera de eso, mi preocupación principal es la comunidad, sobretodo los usuarios nuevos. Si algún usuario por más experimentado que sea logra que los nuevos se vayan o dejen de participar, ese usuario se convierte en un problema para mí.

Answer (score 2):

La existencia del problema es innegable.

He aquí otro ejemplo : [¿Como puedo Crear una interfaz grafica en java solo programando?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22677/como-puedo-crear-una-interfaz-grafica-en-java-solo-programando)

No es una pregunta estelar. Pero está bastante bien.

- Tiene una descripción clara del problema
- El código no es mínimo pero sí pequeño, en un par de minutos se ve el error
- El código aportado es completo y verificable.

El único problema que tiene es que el título no es muy bueno. Hubiese sido mejor algo del estilo : ¿Cómo solucionar java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared?

Y es una pregunta de un novato, es la primera que hace. ¡Ojalá todos los novatos hiciesen su primera pregunta así de bien!

Se me hace muy difícil considerar que un voto de cierre así sea un error, no puedo más que pensar que es un acto de mala fe.

Y creo que la solución no es tomar medidas especiales. Sino ser más activo en los votos positivos a las preguntas y respuestas. Y en visitar las colas de revisión para votar por dejar abiertas las preguntas si no corresponde ser cerradas. Sobretodo si son de novatos y no se les ha dado al menos un tiempo de mejorarla en caso de que sea necesario. Y hay que votar para reabrir las cerradas incorrectamente, que también se puede.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que los votos para cerrar esa pregunta son un problema, pero creo que difieren del tema planteado por Miquel. Me parece que este no es un caso de cierre sin comentarios, sino de cierre por desconocimiento (o por motivos que al menos yo no comprendo).

Comment: Ya había votos de cierre en esa pregunta cuando no había ningún comentario a la pregunta. Y el único comentario a la pregunta que hay en el momento de escribir esto es el mío, y yo no he votado para cerrarla.

Comment: Lo sé ([podés ver la revisión](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/13705)). Solamente que me parecían casos diferentes, pero si es para aportar más ejemplos, bienvenido.

Comment: Razón tienes, es un caso diferente.

Comment: Yo creo que es otro ejemplo más de cierre sin comentario, efectivamente. Creo que la situación se está corrigiendo poco a poco.