# ¿Introducimos los review audits?

Tags: discusión, auditorías-de-revisión

Hace ya unos días creé la publicación [Un gran poder conlleva una gran responsabilidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/796/7242) donde la comunidad compartió sus opiniones.

El único tema común y en el que todo el mundo parece que compartió su opinión favorable fueron los [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121).

Por eso propongo y pregunto a la comunidad (y también, *y es muy importante*, la opinión de los moderadores sobre si es posible implementarlo aquí):

¿Introducimos los review audits?

Comment: Y si mejor nos esforzamos en hacer preguntas útiles que merezcan buenas respuestas, en responder en tono didáctico las preguntas que estén a nuestro alcance, en __*provocar*__ contenido (preguntas y respuestas) de calidad que atraiga mas usuarios. Hay que lograr la masa crítica de preguntas que nos permita salir de beta. En este momento, dedicarle tiempo a discutir sobre las _reviews audits_ no es pertinente (ver [optimización prematura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizaci%C3%B3n_prematura). Ya habrá tiempo después. _My three cents_.

Comment: El problema es que se cierran o se hacen malas revisiones demasiadas veces. Si eso pasa estamos *perdiendo* calidad precisamente.

Comment: _"Demasiadas"_ es malo. Siempre es mejor tomar decisiones basadas en datos. ¿De cuántas revisiones estamos hablando? ¿Qué porcentaje con respecto al total representan? En fin, en mi opinión esta es otra discusión bizantina. Espero que tomen una buena decisión que ayude a la comunidad.

Comment: Para poner un ejemplo: [esta publicación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13764), [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13813), [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13659), [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13657) y [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13656) por poner recientes han sido revisadas como "no requiere ninguna acción" por el mismo usuario. NO. Muy mal. TODAS requerían alguna acción. (no me acuerdo de cómo hacer links ya :S)

Comment: @MiquelColl acá están (te faltaba el http). [esta publicación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13764), [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13813), [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13659), [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13657) y [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13656)

Comment: El link funciona al parecer si es `http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13764` y no `es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13764`.

Comment: @MiquelColl faltó `http://`. Actualicé tu comentario para facilitar su lectura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una mejora debería tener ciertas características que la hagan **pertinente**:

- **oportuna**, debe llegar en el momento en que se requiera. No antes. No después,
- **efectiva**, debe cumplir con los requisitos establecidos. Hacer lo que se supone que tiene que hacer, y
- **económica**, rápida y sin mayores trámites. Porque el tiempo es nuestro recurso más valioso.

Estoy seguro que tu percepción es real, el problema que te anima a proponer estas auditorias **es importante**. Yo también estoy convencido que las malas revisiones existen y son un problema importante que debemos atender. Solo que no es el momento, no solo de atenderlas, ni siquiera de discutirlas, porque no es pertinente.

Mira, pones cuatro ejemplos de malas revisiones y seguramente hay más. Podrías poner diez o veinte. Y si tuvieras tiempo, encontrarías cien o 200 o mil revisiones malas.

Y ese es el problema. El indicador es muy **costoso**. Y es muy costoso porque es **subjetivo**. Requiere que la gente se tome el tiempo de revisar y con su mejor intención *decida* si la revisión es buena o mala. El riesgo que se desarrollen criterios dogmáticos, gente que está convencida que tiene la razón respecto a una decisión, podría presentarse.

Por el contrario, [te propongo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/854/introducci%c3%b3n-de-los-review-audits#comment1958_854) dedicar nuestro tiempo y esfuerzo a otra cosa.

Digo en ese comentario *hacer preguntas útiles que merezcan buenas respuestas y responder en tono didáctico las preguntas que estén a nuestro alcance*. Pero vamos a eliminar el componente subjetivo quitando los adjetivos en la propuesta:

#### Hacer preguntas para que la gente las responda y contestar las preguntas que estén a nuestro alcance.

Dicen que no se puede mejorar lo que no se puede medir. Y para lo que propongo hay una medición o indicador, que no requiere tanto tiempo como el tuyo, este es automático:

[image: Captura de Area 51]
(Captura tomada de http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish en septiembre 7 de 2016 a las 9:15 am)

Revisemos las características de esta propuesta:

- Es medible. Tiene un indicador *objetivo*, no está basada en percepciones, está sustentada en datos.
- Es *económica*, de hecho, solo tenemos que seguir haciendo lo que se supone que tenemos que hacer: seguir preguntando y contestando.
- Es *oportuna*, según el área 51, el porcentaje de preguntas contestadas necesita más trabajo.
- Es *efectiva*, cada pregunta contestada afecta al indicador.

Para terminar, esta propuesta, tiene un propósito retador pero alcanzable: *ayudarnos a salir de beta*.

## Conlusión

Lo que tenemos que hacer es hacer preguntas y contestar.

No, no es tiempo de las auditorias de revisiones. Ni siquiera es tiempo de discutirlas.

Comment: Cosas que he visto sobre responder, entiendo que no son medibles (es decir requieren que un humano revisen las preguntas). 1) Existe la respuesta, pero está a) entre los comentarios; b) como update a la pregunta. 2) la pregunta está incompleta o es difícil comprensión para poder dar una respuesta.

Comment: Podrías ganar por volumen, pero tal vez (mi opinión) a costa de la calidad.

Comment: Claro. Estoy seguro que mi propuesta tiene fallas. Yo creo que la idea principal de mi propuesta es que no busco controlar el comportamiento de otras personas, sino el comportamiento propio. Tipo: _si quieres cambiar el mundo, cambia tu primero_. Eso no lo cuento, pero cuenta mucho.

Comment: Por otro lado, hay como 2000 preguntas sin respuestas, eso quiere decir que habría que responder cerca de 1000 para llegar al 90%. Y mantener algo así como 36 respuestas a las 40 preguntas diarias.

Comment: ¡Exacto! Hay cosas que mejorar antes que ponernos a auditar las revisiones.

Comment: Agrego, siguiendo con el tema estadístico. Hoy se responden algo así como 28 preguntas al día de un ideal de 36. Posiblemente falte a) reclutar expertos que quieran responder; b) motivar a que la gente responda sus preguntas si lo han resuelto.

Comment: Masomenos... pero, en general, los usuarios individuales (tal vez ni como colectivo) tenemos recursos para esas dos opciones. En cambio, tu tienes recursos para preguntar (tal vez traducir buenas preguntas de SO) y responder (tus propias preguntas, tal vez). Para que un proceso sea efectivo, debes tenerlo en control. Y si estamos frente a un monitor, no podemos controlar lo que hacen los demás, intentarlo si, pero el único _asset_ que está realmente bajo tu control, eres tú mismo. Las soluciones deben empezar por la primera persona del singular.

Comment: Pensando en mejorar la relación respuestas/preguntas si genero preguntas pueden pasar dos cosas a) No hay respuesta, resta en el objetivo; b) Hay respuesta, suma 0 al objetivo. Por lo que, desde mi punto de vista, al menos hasta mejorar la relación, la mejor estrategia es simplemente contestar. Ojo, el planteo es netamente numérico o min/max. Para mí hay otras cosas en juego.

Comment: Consulta aparte, ¿sin respuesta => las respuesta que pudieran tener no han sido aceptadas?

Comment: No creo que una pregunta con respuesta sume cero al objetivo, porque entonces el objetivo estaría en 0% y no en 73%. En fin.

Comment: @toledano +1 Estoy de acuerdo que la prioridad ahora es dar más respuestas al gran volumen de preguntas nuevas que se hacen todos los días. Ese número no ha hecho más que bajar desde que comenzó a subir el número de usuarios.

Comment: ¿Es posible ver las mismas estadísticas para SOen? Por ejemplo contando solo las preguntas formuladas el último año.

Comment: @toledano También soy un ferviente creyente en basarnos en datos duros para tomar [decisiones informadas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-informed_decision-making). Sin embargo, no me convence tomar un valor que [no sabemos cómo se calcula](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/25289/144602) y que, si bien sirve como indicador, no es una condición necesaria para graduar al sitio (especialmente porque SO [tiene un menor porcentaje](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name)  y el de SOpt [no es tanto más alto](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name))

Comment: Muy interesante esa pregunta en Area51, Mariano. A ver qué responden.