# ¿Está correctamente la puesta en espera de la pregunta [¿Cómo se denomina el par de corchetes en cada uso diferente?]?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, moderación, pregunta-específica

Debido a la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3597/22539) de [@jose antonio dura olmos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/301/jose-antonio-dura-olmos) no manifestaré mi acuerdo ni desacuerdo en esta publicación, sino me referire a un dato relevante para mi, ¿tenemos un sistema eficiente para saber si las preguntas cerradas o puestas en espera son correctamente cerradas o puestas en espera?.

Yo soy un usuario más activo de SOen que de SOes por lo que mi perspectiva será esa, será de comparar de la forma de como se cierran preguntas. En SOen la mayoria de preguntas son cerradas por los usuarios de alta reputación que pasamos inicialmente por un sistema de auditorias para saber si una pregunta es correcta o no, si el cierre de una pregunta es correcta o no, y si tenemos fallas tenemos sanciones.

Y yo veo que en SOes no existe ese sistema haciendo muy fácil cerrar preguntas para vanalmente tratar de ganar medallas, o sencillamente marcar por marcar sin tomarse el tiempo en revisarlo correctamente.

He visto preguntas relativas a establecer los *audits*:

- [Introducción de los review audits](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/854/introducci%C3%B3n-de-los-review-audits) [07/09/16]
- [Ya nos graduamos, habiliten los audits en las colas de revision](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2572/ya-nos-graduamos-habiliten-los-audits-en-las-colas-de-revision) [28/07/17]
- [Un gran poder conlleva una gran responsabilidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/796/un-gran-poder-conlleva-una-gran-responsabilidad) [26/08/16]

Donde se indican en muchos de ellos que no es posible por diversos motivos, asi que hoy 04/08/18 pregunta que si es posible inplementarlo o sino buscar una solución alternativa.

La raiz de mi pregunta fue al revisar la pregunta [¿Cómo se denomina el uso de los corchetes en cada caso?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185771/c%C3%B3mo-se-denomina-el-par-de-corchetes-en-cada-uso-diferente), la pregunta es simple, y propia de un principiante, en SOen de seguro se la marcaria como duplicada porque deberia existir, pero aqui no existe, no sé si somos muy elitistas o menospreciamos las preguntas simples, pero de las preguntas simples salen las mejores respuestas. La pregunta es concreta y directa, por lo que no deberia ser cerrada como *no está claro lo que se pregunta*, y lo que me sorprende que un *diamantado* lo haga junto a usuarios de reputación alta.

**Aclaración:**

Asumiendo que la pregunta no es correcta, ¿el motivo de cierre es el correcto?,¿esa pregunta no es clara?, si es asi, ¿en que parte no es clara?, ustedes señalan que el OP esta equivocado pero eso es justamente nuestra labor, señalar que es incorrecto que es un operador o no, indicar los fundamentos, etc asi no solo ayudamos al usuario actual sino a todos los futuros usuarios, que el usuario no quiera o sea terco no implica a que sea una mala pregunta, esa es la decisión del OP. **Asi que le pido nuevamente que me indique si el motivo de cierre es el correcto.**

Cada uno tiene la libertad de cerrar la pregunta, nadie obliga a seguir lo que el anterior hizo, y lo mismo para el moderador, ¿piensa que una pregunta asi debe ser cerrada?

Cerrar una pregunta por un motivo que claramente no coincide genera confusión porque usuarios nuevos pueden pensar que el motivo de cierre no es necesario, entonces propongo desde ahora eliminar los motivos y solo indicar un unico motivo: *Yo quiero cerrar la pregunta*.

¿Qué estandares no se cumplio en esta pregunta?

Comment: No eres el único que ve problemas en la calidad de las revisiones : [Febrero 2018 - ¿un mes de revisiones malas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3284/febrero-2018-un-mes-de-revisiones-malas?rq=1). Ni el único que quiere audits : [Introducción de los review audits](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/854/introducci%c3%b3n-de-los-review-audits#comment1958_854). Pero dos años después, y pese al apoyo de miembros de peso, sigue igual. Mientras dependamos de una empresa privada estadounidense seremos un sitio de segunda.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos No estoy de acuerdo con tu visión, no me interesa de que pais sea, lo que sucede hace 2 años no necesariamente debe suceder ahora.

Comment: Ojalá el tiempo demuestre que estoy equivocado. Que tengas suerte.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos yo no quiero solucionar todos los problemas, quiero que tengamos claros que preguntas merecen ser cerradas o no, por ello prefiero atacar un problema en concreto, que un usuario de poca reputación cierre una pregunta asi lo espero(por la falta de experiencia) pero usuarios de alta reputación, y peor un moderador, si él no entiende que son malas o buenas preguntas entonces que esperamos del resto

Comment: Mi opinión personal: la pregunta que mencionas en concreto no es que sea simple, es que no es buena. No es cuestión de ser elitistas o de menospreciar preguntas simples, es que "¿cómo se llama esto?" no es una pregunta de programación y [no se ajusta bien a los temas definidos en el Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (vale que luego pregunta por otros tipos/usos de corchetes, pero la pregunta no deja de ser "¿cómo se llaman los corchetes?")

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro podrias indicarme a cual de los requisitos no se cumplen, no solo señalar que no se ajusta, muchas veces se puede dar un nombre distinto al elemento gráfico segun el contexto por lo que la pregunta es válida, se puedo responder: *el unico nombre que tiene es corchete, su uso es esto, y esto, debe cumplir estas reglas, etc.* Y por ultimo, lo más importante, tu como moderador podrias indicarme si el motivo de cierre es el correcto

Comment: @eyllanesc Ser moderador no me hace omnisciente. Si el motivo es correcto o no, es relativo. Como decía en mi anterior comentario, la pregunta no me parece realmente una pregunta que se ajuste bien al formato/temática del sitio: el usuario pregunta por el nombre de algo, no por su uso concreto (que incluye en la pregunta). Luego se pregunta por otros tipos de uso para el corchete que es algo que de podría considerar pertinente al sitio aunque algo amplio o que no queda del todo claro (sería diferente si se pusiera un ejemplo concreto y se preguntara por ese caso particular).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Yo no dije que seas omnisciente sino que el moderador muchas veces tiene más experiencia que los otros usuarios porque revisa más casos de este tipo, no piensas que con lo que señalas el motivo adecuado de cierre sería *demasiado amplia*

Comment: @eyllanesc Perdón, no fue el comentario más acertado por mi parte. Sí, por lo que digo, quizás habría votado como demasiado amplia o no relacionada... o me habría abstenido (intento no votar mucho a no ser que sea un caso claro por aquello de que mi voto es definitivo).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro *pero la pregunta no deja de ser "¿cómo se llaman los corchetes?* Y la respuesta, que nadie ha dado en los comentarios, es **separadores**. Mejor sería si la pregunta fuese "¿Cual es el elemento no terminal de la gramática del lenguaje Java al que pertenecen los corchetes?" Pero la pregunta solo puede ser escrita de esa forma por quien ya conoce la respuesta. Esa pregunta, que sí es de programacíon pues conocer en profundidad la JLS es útil para programar en Java, no puede ser formulada mejor por quien no conoce la respuesta.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos de nuevo, todo es relativo. A mi parecer "_¿Cómo se llama esto?_" no es una pregunta práctica de programación. Tal como veo la pregunta, sería equivalente a ir al sitio de automoción y preguntar "_¿Cómo se llaman esas cosas redondas que giran y hacen que el coche se mueva? (añadiendo foto de una rueda) ¿Y hay algo parecido en el resto del coche?_" ¿Tiene una respuesta concreta? Sí (aunque estaría abierta a interpretaciones). ¿Se podría considerar eso una pregunta de automoción? No realmente. Pues esto es igual: ¿qué son los corchetes? (ejemplo de array) ¿hay otros?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Estoy de acuerdo contigo en que es relativo. Tu punto de vista es válido. Y además es el predominante. Por eso SOes es como es.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos no sé si en [so.ru] tienen audits. Parece que [en breve cambiarán el CM dedicado a los SO internacionales y que lo será el de ese sitio (Nicolas)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313084/209901), lo que podría dar un impulso a este tipo de iniciativas necesarias y auténticamente ignoradas.

Comment: @eyllanesc En mi opinión tu punto se cumple perfectamente. Si bien es cierto que no tiene una estructura muy correcta, el tema que trata si que me parece curioso y con una pequeña edición seria una pregunta interesante,sin embargo ha sido cerrado enseguida sin pestañear. Y en este punto me hace pensar "Si con una pequeña edición puede ser una buena pregunta, porque se ha ido a cerrarla en vez de mejorarla?"

Comment: @CristianS9 Voy a hacer de abogado del diablo. Si con una edición pasa de mala pregunta a buena pregunta entonces ponerla en espera es justo lo que hay que hacer. Y dejando la abogacía, hay quienes pensamos que sí, se puede mejorar, pero como está es suficiente.

Answer (score 4):

Con esta forma demasiado estricta de poner en espera preguntas estamos consiguiendo que no se cumpla lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desafortunadamente asistimos a un caso doble de algún comentario no constructivo y de puesta en espera incorrecta por ignorancia.

> Creo que no acabo de entender ninguna de tus preguntas.

Los comentarios tienen como propósito ayudar a mejorar la pregunta. Si quien escribió este comentario hubiese puesto por qué no lo entiende entonces habría sido un buen comentario. El comentario no es constructivo.

> Si no me equivoco, en las tres expresiones con corchetes, cada par de corchetes es un operador diferente.

Aquí el AO deja claro que algo sí ha investigado. No tiene un desconocimiento total sobre los corchetes. Ya quedaba claro en su pregunta con los ejemplos de código. Pero aquí además el AO muestra que se preocupa por su pregunta y responde a comentarios. Si no edita la pregunta para mejorarla es porque no es necesario.

> No. Los corchetes son corchetes. No tienen nombre. El lenguaje, agnosticamente, los usa como una estructura de control para significar algo. Como el punto y coma, se usa asi porque el lenguaje tiene una gramatica que dice que el tamaño de un vector se escribe entre corchetes, y la posicion de un vector se escribe entre corchetes. A esto te referis?

Aquí hay una mezcla de conceptos correctos e incorrectos que demuestran un buen, pero no excelente, conocimiento del lenguaje Java. Es cierto que el lenguaje tiene una gramática. No es cierto que los corchetes no tengan nombre. Y hay una cuestión fundamental, que no se menciona en ningún comentario, que es la verdadera respuesta a la pregunta. Los corchetes pertenecen a una **categoría** (estrictamente a un elemento no terminal de la gramática del lenguaje Java). Pertenecen a una categoría muy concreta, y una cita de la Java Language Specification serviría para aclarar al AO que los corchetes no son operadores (al contrario de lo que ocurre en C++) y sí son **Separadores**.

```
3.11 Separadores
Doce tokens, formados por caracteres ASCII, son los separadores (puntuadores).
Separador:
(uno de)
(   )   {   }   [   ]   ;   ,   .   ...   @   ::

3.12 Operadores
38 tokens, formados por caracteres ASCII, son los operadores.
Operador:
(uno de)
=   >   <   !   ~   ?   :   ->
==  >=  <=  !=  &&  ||  ++  --
+   -   *   /   &   |   ^   %   <<   >>   >>>
+=  -=  *=  /=  &=  |=  ^=  %=  <<=  >>=  >>>=
```

> [] corchetes, () parentesis, {} llaves. Los corchetes son corchetes y
>   no tienen otro nombre y se usan para arreglos y las tres formas que
>   pones son arreglos. Las dos primeras es una sola expresión de
>   inicialización que separaste, pero si coloca de forma completa es así:
>   int[] a = new int[10]; y la 3ra es solo el uso de ese arreglo. Esta es
>   la precedencia de operadores java [] y nunca se sobrecargan y son el
>   operador de mayor precedencia:

Otro ejemplo de información incorrecta. Los corchetes no son operadores en Java. Lamentablemente esto resulta en :

> Claro que no se sobrecarga si en Java no existe sobrecarga. Menos mal que alguien por fin a confirmmado que los corchetes es operador.

Fantástico. Esto hemos conseguido al poner en espera la pregunta, que el AO se vaya de su visita a Stack Overflow en español sabiendo menos y peor que cuando entró. **¿Así se consigue un sitio de calidad?**

Rectificar es de sabios.

- Reabramos esta pregunta.
- Seamos más humildes antes de poner en espera una pregunta.
- No usemos la puesta en espera por privilegio de moderador salvo en casos **excepcionales**.

Comment: De acuerdo en gran parte de lo mencionado, pero me parece pertinente resaltar que el estado actual de la pregunta no es [cerrado] sino [puesto en espera]. En cuanto a la virtud de humildad no considero que su grado tenga que ver con la acción de votar para cerrar, pero sí en la forma en la que explicamos los motivos y criterios. Reflejar la aspectos de personalidad como la humildad al tiempo que ser concisos es un gran reto y digno de admiración en quienes lo logran.

Comment: @Rubén De acuerdo, puesta en espera. La substancia de la respuesta no cambia.

Comment: Sigo sin entender porque no se arregla la pregunta a algo que corresponda. Y no, los corchetes son corchetes y si queres pertenecen a una categoria de la gramatica llamada separadores, como el while y el for son iteradores. La pregunta sigue preguntando como se llama a los corchetes. y se llaman corchetes.

Comment: @gbianchi Pues no, while y for no son iteradores ni en C++ ni en Java. En Java son palabras clave (keywords), véase 3.9 Keywords en [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf). En C++ son declaraciones (statements), véase A.5 Statements en [C++ standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf). En C++ son *iteration-statements*, que es algo muy distito de un *iterator*. Verdaderamente estas preguntas básicas hacen mucha falta en SOes y ponerlas en espera hace un flaco favor a la comunidad.

Comment: Como puntualización, creo que te equivocas en tu primer argumento. `Creo que no acabo de entender ninguna de tus preguntas.` yo entiendo que no se refiere a otras preguntas (ya que de hecho, era la primera), sino a ninguna de las preguntas del post. Eso invalidaría tanto tu consideración de  que es un argumento ad hominem, como que no estaba siendo amable. Es un comentario normal indicando que las preguntas no eran claras (para el autor del comentario).

Comment: @Pikoh Es otra forma de interpretar el comentario. Ahora no puedo contrastarlo con la pregunta pues fue borrada. Pero ante la duda debo verlo bajo la luz lo más favorable posible. Con lo que, de acuerdo, no sería un ataque ad hominem. Sin embargo sigue sin ser amable. Creo que eso era el comentario entero, no una parte. Decir que no entiende las preguntas y nada más no es constructivo. Y lo veo más cerca del tercer ejemplo poco amistoso del [Código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) que del amistoso.

Comment: Bueno, todo es interpretable, yo no lo interpreto como poco amistoso aunque si podría haber extendido el comentario tratando de aclarar sus dudas. Y si, era el comentario completo (yo si tengo acceso a la pregunta eliminada) Al final es algo subjetivo y es difícil interpretar la intención de alguien al hacer un comentario escrito :)

Answer (score 3):

Esto es totalmente mi punto de vista:

Cuando vi la pregunta por primera vez, no pregunta sobre el uso de los corchetes, ni siquiera en que casos hay que ponerlos o no. La pregunta dice:

> ¿Cómo se denomina el par de corchetes en cada uso diferente?

No es una pregunta sobre su uso en el lenguaje. Es mas, OP da ejemplos de su uso.

Aparte de eso, no demuestra nada de investigación. Solo dice que se deben llamar de distinta forma.

La pregunta recibio un monton de comentarios, y el usuario solo dijo que eran `operadores` diferentes. Se le aclaro que no eran operadores. Sin embargo el usuario insistio por ese camino, es mas, quejandose que realmente eran operadores.

Volvemos al punto inicial entonces. El usuario no pregunta sobre el uso de los mismos, referenciando aunque sea una página que le dio información incompleta o erronea. El usuario pregunta el nombre de los corchetes.

Si alguien quisiera escribir una pregunta sobre el uso de los corchetes, el uso de las llaves, el uso de los parentesis, no habria ninguna clase de problemas, mientras la pregunta sea clara respecto a eso y demuestre algo de investigación, aunque la misma sea, encontre la definición del lenguaje, pero esta todo en ingles.

Igual entre el momento de la pregunta, y el cierre, pasaron varias horas. Las reglas tambien permiten a quien pregunto averiguar sobre el motivo del cierre y mejorar su pregunta, cosa que no paso ya que la unica edición fue para mejorar su formato (y yo puedo decir que fui quien rechazo dicha ediciòn, ya que la pregunta tenia mayores problemas que eso).

Como corolario, el primer voto de cierre no fue mio, fue de un usuario al que podemos considerar mas liberal en cuanto al cierre de preguntas (eso es, si quisieramos formar equipos, tengo una vision opuesta con el respecto a que es valido y que no lo es). Sin embargo, el tambien opino sobre el cierre.

Mi pedido de cierre a un mod, fue porque en el estado de la pregunta y con la cantidad de comentarios que recibia, podia llegar a recibir una respuesta de todavia peor calidad.

Y todo esto, no invalida lo que dije mas temprano, alguien puede mejorar la pregunta, o hacer una pregunta precisamente dedicada al uso de los corchetes en el lenguaje. Y si es un usuario con o sin experiencia, no importa, sobre todo si la pregunta es autocontestada.

PD: en caso de dudas, revisen el [historial de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/185771/timeline)

Comment: Tú indicas: *el primer voto de cierre no fue mio*, esa no es excusa para indicar un motivo de cierre incorrect, me podrias indicar tu motivo de cierres, y ¿por qué?, Si las posibles respuestas son de mala calidad, ¿como adivinaste ello?, no piensas que la comunidad puede lidiar con ello señalandolo con downvotes.

Comment: No no. Lo del orden de los votos de cierre  no es una excusa. Si eso suena a excusa de algun tipo lo saco. Creo que pediste que justificara el pq de mi voto de cierre, y eso quise hacer. Indique el orden de los votos por la cuestion de q el otro usuario que voto es justamente alguien que suele tener una postura contraria a la mia. Recuerda q hasta que no se cierra, no se sabe quien voto. Y mi explicacion esta leyendo los primeros parrafos, 0 investigacion, poco claro que se pregunta, poca ayuda del usuario para aclararla.

Comment: Por ello mi pregunta, ¿cual de las opciones señalaste?, ¿No esta claro lo que se pregunta?, ¿Qué no esta claro?

Comment: Eso. Que se pregunta. La pregunta dice como se denomina el par de corchetes en cada uso diferente. Como se denomina. Como se llama. Se llama corchetes. No es claro que se pregunta. No existe un motivo, es una pregunta retorica.

Comment: Existen elementos que por su uso tienen un nombre distinto, porque no pensar que el OP no lo sabia, e indicar en una respuesta que el corchete no tiene otro nombre, que no es un operador, y punto.

Comment: Se le indico en comentarios. No alcanza con eso? La respuesta que diria lo mismo que el comentario, no seria de baja calidad. Seria de bajisima.

Comment: Indicar *no es algo* es una respuesta, no toda respuesta debe ser afirmativa, ¿o piensas que las respuestas de buena calidad solo deben ser afirmativas? ¿en qué basas que es de bajísima calidad?, la respuesta sería clara y concisa

Comment: Muestrame una respuesta clara, concisa y que no parezca un comentario como los que estan escritos y apoyo tu idea. Los comentarios contestan la pregunta, y ninguno tiene el nivel como para alcanzar a ser una respuesta. No hablo de respuestas positivas o negativas. Hablo de tenes una respuesta de calidad. Un "no se puede" es una respuesta valida, pero no iria en el campo de respuesta. No toda pregunta tiene una respuesta. A veces la respuesta es una palabra.

Comment: @gbianchi No puedo, la pregunta está cerrada. Y no, los comentarios no responden la pregunta. De hecho hacen lo contrario, difunden información errónea.

Answer (score 1):

Llego tarde a la discusión, pero me gustaría dar mi opinión personal sobre todas las cuestiones tratadas en este post, en el que creo por un lado que se han ido mezclando varias cuestiones complejas, y por otro se aprecian las diferentes tendencias que existen en nuestra comunidad.

Primero, vamos a lo que yo entiendo que es la cuestión principal de la pregunta de @eyllanesc: **los audits**. Como bien se ha dicho, es algo que se ha pedido en numerosas ocasiones y en lo que creo que la gran mayoría de usuarios estamos de acuerdo, con lo que hay poco que decir. Son necesarios para que los privilegios obtenidos se usen con responsabilidad.

Ahora, trataré de analizar la pregunta que ocasiona toda esta discusión. En mi opinión no es una pregunta con la calidad suficiente para el sitio.

> la pregunta es simple, y propia de un principiante, en SOen de seguro se la marcaria como duplicada porque deberia existir, pero aqui no existe

¿Estás seguro de que una pregunta así ya existe en SOen? Yo lo dudo (he intentado buscarla sin éxito, si tienes un enlace me gustaría verlo). Para mi, preguntar por el nombre de un elemento de un lenguaje determinado demuestra una falta de investigación previa (requisito que yo considero imprescindible para realizar una pregunta en el sitio), ya que obviamente es algo que se encontrará siempre en la referencia del lenguaje. Se que hay usuarios que abogan porque en StackOverflow en Español se admitan preguntas teóricas que están perfectamente respondidas en las diferentes documentaciones propias de cada lenguaje, pero yo no soy uno de ellos.

En lo que si puedo estar de acuerdo es en que la razón no es la mas adecuada, pero aquí vamos a algo que yo ya he señalado en otras ocasiones: En SOes no tenemos el mismo numero de razones de cierre que en SOen, lo que muchas veces provoca que haya que elegir una razón de cierre que no es la mas ajustada a lo que debería ser. Eso es algo que ya se pidió también y creo recordar que se dijo que no era posible.

Por último (no quiero extenderme demasiado) me parece curioso que se llame la atención sobre la celeridad de cierre de preguntas cuando el problema **es exactamente el contrario**.Solo hay que darse una vuelta por la cola de cierre de preguntas para ver que hay cientos (literalmente) de preguntas en dicha cola. En el momento en el que escribo esto, hay 19 preguntas con 4 o 3 votos de cierre, y pueden quedarse en esta situación durante mucho tiempo. Hay un problema de moderación evidente en el sitio, y entiendo que los 3 moderadores tengan en ocasiones que hacer "limpieza" usando su voto definitivo, algo que desde luego está muy lejos del ideal, que como bien dice @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos en una situación normal solo debería ser usado en casos excepcionales.

P.D. Veo varias referencias al nuevo código de conducta de la red StackExchange, pero en el caso que nos ocupa no aprecio infracción alguna del mismo. De hecho, hay varios comentarios explicando al OP la necesidad de editar la pregunta para ajustarla a lo aceptable y tratando de guiarle en ello, enlazándole al Recorrido y otros recursos útiles. En ningún caso veo comentarios ofensivos (tal vez el mas ofensivo es del op: `A ti te parece, pero a Strostrup, no.`). Al final, el cierre de una pregunta en ocasiones tiene un componente subjetivo, y por ello es mejor que los moderadores no intervengan en el cierre, ya que así el cierre debe pasar por el criterio de 5 personas diferentes.

Comment: Tienes razón en que la respuesta a la pregunta se encuentra en la referencia del lenguaje, concretamente en la Java Language Specification y en el C++ standard. Entiendo aunque no comparto tu punto de vista sobre preguntas que se pueden responder consultando la referencia. Pero en este caso hay un elemento adicional a considerar, ninguna de esas dos referencias están disponibles en castellano. Al citar y traducir parte de estas referencias para esta pregunta estaríamos creando un contenido que no existe en internet. Al menos yo no las he encontrado.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos bien, entiendo tu punto de vista. Si bien es cierto que para programar es casi imprescindible cierto conocimiento de inglés ya que habitualmente cualquier especificación/documentación está en este idioma, también es cierto que hay personas que no lo dominan. El tema es complejo, ya que si bien se podría admitir una pregunta de este tipo al no existir el recurso en español, podemos terminar con un número excesivo de preguntas que cubrieran toda la especificación de un lenguaje, que suele ser bastante extensa. Es complicado alcanzar un equilibrio creo.