# Esta pregunta fue cerrada pero a la vez fue la pregunta más visitada el mes de octubre. ¿La reabrimos?

Tags: discusión

Se ha publicado el [segundo reporte del estado de Stack Overflow en español](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/El-estado-de-Stack-Overflow-en-espanol-2/). En las estadísticas compartidas, se vio que la [pregunta más visitada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26313/consulta-sobre-desarrollar-una-ia-inteligencia-artificial/27020#27) el mes de octubre fue cerrada por ser demasiada amplia en enfoque.  Pero, al ver que la popularidad de esa pregunta sigue creciendo, tal vez estaría bien el volver a abrirla.

¿Qué piensan ustedes?

Comment: Me parece un tema interesante pero igual que muchos otros que no se tratan en este sitio. 
Puede que haya tenido tantas visitas por la polémica, porque estuvo bastante *activa* (en cuanto a comentarios y respuestas) y la recompensa ofrecida.

Comment: Yo creo que se debería reabrir, sin embargo se debería protegerla para evitar comentarios como respuestas.

Comment: He votado para reabrirla... Tal vez hace falta corregir algún que otro detalle de gramática... La cerraron porque no se ajusta a las políticas de Stack Overflow, se basa solo en pedir tutoriales o alguna orientación sobre el tema.

Comment: Entiendo que recibió muchas visitas en parte porque tuvo una recompensa de @ArtEze. Eso siempre ayuda. En cuanto a la pregunta en sí, nótese que consiste en _ ¿Qué libros, temas, comunidades, podrían agregar? Eso según su experiencia en el campo, o consejos que me puedan dar_. Para mí esto toca dos elementos perniciosos: demasiado amplia, basado en opiniones y petición de enlaces. Al fin y al cabo, es difícil determinar cuál es la respuesta buena y probablemente todas lo sean.

Comment: @ArtEze Si se te ocurre forma de editarla para que deje de ser una pregunta de opinión, sería genial que lo hicieras. Yo no puedo imaginarme cómo podría editarse sin invalidar las respuestas.

Comment: Entiendo el objetivo de fondo @JuanM, pero 737 vistas (al momento de este comentario) no parecería ser un número tan abismal. Creo que sería interesante evaluar cuántos de esos hits vienen de buscadores y cuántos desde adentro de SOes, para diferenciar si tuvo que ver la recompensa o si realmente atrae tráfico al sitio. En mi opinión, esta es una pregunta con la que nos dejamos **jugar** un rato antes de cerrarla. Creo que eso sería una buena propuesta para Meta: *¿Está bien postergar un cierre en una pregunta de opinión pero que puede ser interesante ver cómo se desarrolla unos días?*

Comment: Se me hace una mala practica hacer excepciones de las excepciones.

Comment: La ley es para todos, esa pregunta no cumple con los requisitos de SO, además reabrirla solo porque es popular no me parece un motivo válido, el fin de SO es ayudar a resolver problemas puntuales, no recomendar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No

- Es una pregunta que pide opiniones, **si aceptas esta, deberías aceptar todas**.
- Las preguntas que piden [lista de cosas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/585/podr%C3%ADamos-permitir-preguntas-que-sean-listas-de-cosas), ya se habían rechazado antes.
- Es [demasiado amplia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), no presenta un problema concreto.

Finalmente, que tenga muchas visitas **no la convierte *automáticamente* en una buena pregunta**. Tal vez te convenga reabrirla por cuestión de billete, pero **claramente** incumple con las políticas de la calidad.

En todo caso, que se revisen estas políticas, para que **las preguntas con muchas visitas NO PUEDAN CERRARSE**. O para que se acepten preguntas que pidan opiniones, recomendaciones o ideas.

Pero que aplique para todos...

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. O todas o ninguna. Y para preguntas que se basan en opiniones, prefiero que ninguna.

Comment: En el sitio en inglés se aceptan [preguntas basadas en opiniones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Unas pocas puntuales no como tónica general. Esto no es el sitio inglés, pero en esto sí coicido con ellos.  No tiene por qué ser blanco y negro. Esta pregunta sobre IA bloqueada por moderador y convertida en wiki como en el sitio en inglés no solo no hace daño sino que beneficia al sitio.

Answer (score 6):

## **Debería cerrarse y quedar cerrada.**

La pregunta va **claramente en contra de lo indicado en el Centro de Ayuda** en [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) y [¿Que tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

- No es sobre un problema específico ni un algoritmo ni una herramienta comúnmente usada ni un problema práctico.
- Es una pregunta subjetivas en las que cada respuesta es igualmente válida.
- Es una pregunta muy amplia, poco clara, incompleta o basada en opinión.

Estoy 100% de acuerdo con [la respuesta de toledano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1056/250). Si empezamos a hacer excepciones con una pregunta que no cumple las normas, ¿por qué no hacer excepciones con todas? ¿Quién decide qué preguntas serán permitidas y cuáles no?

Si dejamos abiertas preguntas porque tienen mucho tráfico aunque no cumplan con las normas del sitio, estamos devaluando y prostituyendo el sitio.

El motivo por el que tiene tantas visitas y votos positivos es porque había una recompensa puesta en la pregunta (que por cierto impedía que votaramos por cerrarla antes de que se convirtiera en el *monstruo* que se ha convertido).

El hecho de que casi todas las respuestas sean de gente que no llega (o no llegaba cuando respondieron) a los 200 puntos sin "atraer la atención" de usuarios más experimentados (incluso con la recompensa), debería hacer saltar algunas señales de alarma.

---

Y ahora voy a llevarlo más allá, me voy a granjear mala fama, algunos enemigos y puntos negativos, pero **es hora de subir los requerimientos para alcanzar ciertos privilegios**. La pregunta claramente no se ajusta a los contenidos que se mencionan en el Centro de Ayuda, y es indefendible por cualquiera que se haya leído los dos enlaces de arriba:

1. La persona que preguntó desconoce qué preguntas deben evitarse.
2. La persona que dió la recompensa desconoce sobre qué temas se puede preguntar.
3. Las personas que votaron positivo desconocen la diferencia entre preguntas buenas y malas.
4. Las personas que votaron por reabrir la pregunta desconocen las normas del sitio.

Comprendo que aún somos una comunidad pequeña y que para su buen funcionamiento hace falta que haya bastantes miembros de la comunidad tengan ciertos privilegios, pero esta pregunta es un ejemplo perfecto de cómo muchos de esos miembros no están preparados para hacer uso de unos privilegios que les vienen grandes.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Lo que sí, tendría mucho cuidado en **cómo** subir los privilegios. Creo que si _hoy_ los llevamos a los valores por defecto de un sitio graduado, perderíamos capacidad para cerrar spam y responder rápido a algunas cuestiones (es para verlo en otra pregunta en meta). El hecho de que las colas de revisión estén siempre en cero ya debería ser un buen indicador.

Comment: Sí, llevarlos a los valores de SO sería una locura. Por ejemplo, votar para cerrar/reabrir serían unos excesivos 3.000 puntos que sólo 18 usuarios alcanzarían, pero dejarlo en 500 me parece muy bajo, especialmente teniendo en cuenta que 100 son "gratis" al venir de otro sitio de la red SE.

Comment: Me alegra que estemos orientando hacia el mismo lado. En caso de que te interese analizar más en profundidad los votos de esta pregunta, esta es la tabla con la reputación de cada usuario que votó y cantidades totales: http://pastebin.com/9bedvhfC