# Problema con esta pregunta de swift

Tags: discusión

[Esta pregunta de swift](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35442/leer-c%c3%b3digo-de-verificaci%c3%b3n-sms-desde-ios) ha generado cierta *discusión* y quería que esa discusión se trasladara a [meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Antes de que fuera cerrada ayer por ser **demasiado amplia**, habia ciertas discrepancias sobre si de hecho era demasiado amplia. Yo le comenté al usuario que hizo la pregunta que él sabía como preguntar (tiene muchas preguntas muy bien formuladas y bastante reputación) y le recordaba que esa pregunta que él planteaba abarcaba mucho.

Literalmente le dije que tenian que ser "dudas concretas" (refiriendome a "Esta linea me da error X y no se por qué" pero no me expliqué lo suficiente).
A lo que me contestaron que sí era una pregunta concreta en su opinión y también válida...
 Hombre, preguntar "¿Cómo se formó el universo?" es tambíen bastante concreta, pero admitireis que es sin duda amplia.

Alguien también comentaba algo así como (se han borrado ciertos comentarios de la publicacion, probablemente porque no aportaban mucho al tema): "Sería una pena que se cerrara porque la encuentro interesante".
Esto me recuerda a la [recién discutida pregunta sobre IA](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055/esta-pregunta-fue-cerrada-pero-a-la-vez-fue-la-pregunta-m%C3%A1s-visitada-el-mes-de-o). Sí, es intersante pero no es un requisito indispensable y único en este sitio, ha de tener cabida aquí (esta de swift la tiene) y tener también un formato adecuado, que acote la pregunta.

Bueno, la cosa es que hice lo oportuno, voté para el cierre de dicha pregunta. El resto de la comunidad decidiría. Tras un rato eramos dos votos cuando normalmente las preguntas demasiado amplias se cierran bastante rápido. Entonces llegó un **moderador** y la cerró.

Algo que me sorprende es que desde que se ha cerrado, ha recibido **2 votos positivos** pero lo que me sorprende **aún más** es que sin edición alguna del post (aparte de un título añadiendo [en proceso de reapertura]) hay 4 votos de reapertura ... Y actualmente tiene 4 votos a favor y 2 en contra

Con este post intento que haya debate. Los que votaron a favor/en contra, por qué lo hicieron. Los que votaron para reabrir lo mismo. Y bienvenido el que no haya hecho eso pero quiera opinar.
El sitio está estipulado de una manera pero es la comunidad la que decide. Y esto va evolucionando según nuestras decisiones e intereses.

Comment: Ando confundido, el reporte de "demasiado amplia" se refiere __a las posibles respuestas__ no a las preguntas. _"¿Cómo se formó el universo?"_ parece una pregunta válida, pero las posibles respuestas serían muy amplias para el formato del sitio. Según lo veo, solo hay dos respuestas posibles a la pregunta concreta del OP: si o no, porque es todo lo que necesita saber. Supongo que cuando el OP escribe _"¿**Solo necesito saber si es posible** acceder a la lista de sms y obtener el código sin que el usuario se mueva de la aplicación?"_ la gente entiende otra cosa...

Answer (score 3):

Como ya comenté por el chat, al verla en la cola de revisión me surgieron dudas importantes hasta el punto de que la omití porque no tenia nada claro que hacer con ella.

Primero de todo, si la pregunta se entiende como que desea saber si es o no posible que una app acceda directamente a la lista de SMS, creo que es una pregunta muy concreta. Digo esto porque a mi parecer debería ser más directo en este sentido si es esto lo que desea, el dice literalmente:

> ¿Es posible acceder a la lista de sms y obtener el código sin que el usuario se mueva de la aplicación?

Para mi esto puede llevar a otras interpretaciones que dan lugar a respuestas como la que le dan. Dicha respuesta es en realidad un 'No' y lo que le da son 3 alternativas (aunque la pregunta no pide alternativas si no es posible, en ese caso si seria a mi entender candidata al cierre por ser demasiado amplia).

Si lo que quiere es saber si una app puede o no acceder, yo plantearia la pregunta más directa:

> ¿Es posible hacer que la aplición acceda a la lista de sms y obtenga el código de verificación sin mediación del usuario?

Entendida así no creo que la pregunta sea demasiado amplia, si se quiere responder adecuadamente solo necesita un 'No es posible porque...' o 'Si es posible usando tal o cual método'. 
Otro tema es si debemos aceptar preguntas que se respondan con un 'si' o un 'no' y aquí es donde está mi duda porque, para empezar, depende mucho de la pregunta en si. No es lo mismo preguntar:

> ¿Es posible sumar 2 enteros en c++?

Que algo muy específico sobre una libreria, plataforma, etc y que no se encuentre buscando en google.

Ante mis dudas me fui a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) y busqué a ver si había algo similar a esta pregunta y encontré [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888567/read-verification-code-automatically-and-access-for-login-in-app-in-ios). Es muy parecida aunque no menciona para nada `swift`. Parece que en este caso no suscitó demasiada controversia (tampoco demasiado interés).

En definitiva creo que podria ser válida para el sitio pero tampoco creo que sea una injusticia si se cierra, yo mismo he cambiado de parecer varias veces y puede que dentro de nada crea que deba cerrarse.
. Para mi está en el filo de la navaja como se suele decir.

Comment: Es posible que la pregunta pueda plantearse mejor aunque no veo mucha diferencia entre las dos (la original y la que propones). Por otra parte antes de la edición decía: _"Solo necesito saber si es posible o no"_, ahora se ha editado y dice que en Android es posible pero no sabe si iOS lo permite. Yo soy de la opinión que si una pregunta esta en el límite de ser aceptada o no en el sitio siempre es mejor optar por mantenerla, es más beneficioso para todos. Pero para gustos los colores.

Comment: @blonfu es cierto, realmente no hay diferencia, solo que de esta forma dejas claro sin ninguna duda que lo que quieres es que la propia app, mediante código, acceda a la lista de sms y no que lo haga el usuario sin necesidad de salir de la app y luego entrar de nuevo (esto si nos podría llevar a distintas ideas). No había visto la nueva edición, si la pregunta fuera sobre Android sería distinto, con Android y su gestión de permisos no hay límite para indagar en la privacidad del usuario....XD

Comment: Ok, así explicado entiendo tu postura aunque mi opinión no cambia, sobre todo con la nueva edición que creo que lo aclara un poco más

Answer (score 1):

A mi me parece una pregunta bastante concreta, si preguntara como se hace *tal cosa* sin aportar código ni más datos sería demasiado amplia ya que podría haber muchas manera de hacerlo pero solo quiere saber si es posible o no. Necesita saber si una aplicación puede acceder a los SMS y recuperar un valor de ahí sin que el usuario salga de la app.

Si hay algún método, plugin o técnica para hacer tal cosa, con nombrarlo y decir que es posible es suficiente para contestar la pregunta. Si hay alguna restricción técnica, de permisos, privacidad, etc. que no lo permita también es fácil contestar de forma concreta. Si se cree que no es posible pero no hay nada concreto en que basarse quiza sea más complejo responder, aunque también sería posible responder con cierto rigor.

En mi opinión la pregunta es completamente válida.

Comment: Gracias por tu opinión ^^ Uno de los motivos por lo que, actualmente, una pregunta es considerada *demasiado amplia* es `Existen muchas respuestas posibles` y mismamente la unica respuesta que recibió en el tiempo que estuvo abierta, sugiere 3 respuestas distintas.

Comment: @lois6b viéndolo de esa forma puede ser pero eso ocurre mucho en otras preguntas que no plantean ningún debate, es muy normal que un problema de programación se pueda resolver de tres o cuatro maneras distintas, por poner un ejemplo [cualquiera](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14938/c%c3%b3mo-leo-una-cadena-de-texto-y-a%c3%b1ado-espacios-despu%c3%a9s-de-3-caracteres)

Comment: cierto es... a ver que se saca en claro con todo esto